# How to print all check and print all prime number from an array index?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array each index has a five(5) digit number. I would like to check & print all the prime numbers that are in each of the five digit index. How can I do this?

My code:

```
public static void employeeID() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int emplID[] = { 43233, 71753, 97135 };

    for (int i = 0; i < emplID.length; i++) {
        if ((emplID[i] > 10000) && (emplID[i] < 99999)) {
            System.out.print(emplID[i] + " - Valid ID length\n");

        } else {
            System.out.println(emplID[i] + " - Invalid ID! ID must be Five digits!\n");
            emplID[i] = in.nextInt();
        }

        for (int j = 2; j < emplID[i]; j++) {
            if (emplID[i] % j == 0) {
                // isPrime = false;
                System.out.println(emplID[i] + " - valid prime");
            } else
                System.out.println(emplID[i] + " - not prime");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more info? Does it compile? What does your code do when you run it? Does it throw some kind of exception?

Comment: As we can not see who gave you down vote but I believe we should let new joiner's to ask the question, i do understand the questions can be silly but we should encourage them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track with your commented out line `isPrime = false;`.  Your current problem is that you have your `if` statement inside your `for` loop, which means the program makes a determination about whether the number is prime on the first iteration.  That means that unless the number is divisible by 2, your program prints "not prime" and breaks out of the loop.  You need to use a boolean flag to keep track of whether the number has been declared prime yet, and then only print after the whole loop has completed.  Below is an example of how to do this, with comments at every step:

```
boolean isPrime = true; //assume the number is prime to start with
for (int j = 2; j < emplID[i] / 2; j++) { //you only need to loop up to emplID[i] / 2
    if (emplID[i] % j == 0) { //if the number is divisible by j
        isPrime = false; //set the boolean flag to false (this number is not prime)
        break; //break out of the loop (we have no more testing to do)
    }
}

if (isPrime) { //now that the loop has finished, if the boolean flag is still true, the number must be prime
    System.out.println(emplID[i] + " - valid prime");
} else {
    System.out.println(emplID[i] + " - not prime"); //otherwise, it was divisible by some number in the loop, so it is not prime
}
```

It's worth noting that your test case `{43233, 71753, 97135}` contains only composite numbers, so you aren't really testing your program.  Try adding a number like 14717.

Comment: Well, using my code, it prints out "14717 - valid prime" because 14717 is a prime number.  The program knows this because the `isPrime` flag was never set to false because 14717 wasn't divisible by any of the values of `j`.

Comment: based on the code i have and yours how would you store the data in another method including employee name?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.  I think I would need to see some example code to get a clear picture here.  Maybe you could either send me an example that doesn't work or create a new question with the same?

Comment: I don't have a code at the moment, but what i am trying to do is code an employee database that has the employee name and ID stored. Then prompt the user to enter the employee name,then search through the database and retrieve the corresponding id number or enter the ID and search through the database for the corresponding name. P.S. the code for the question i asked is the ID part of the program.

Comment: How are you storing the database?  Are you using something like mySQL, or is it just written to a text file or something?  If you have any structure so far at all it would help if I could see it.

Comment: No, its not an actual program i'm creating(class assignment). i'll show you what code i have so far

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
 int[] emplID={ 42577, 38611, 32051, 28627, 42061, 52711 };
 int ID = employeeID(emplID);
 String[] emplNames= { "Bruce Wayne", "Barry Allen", "Hal Jordan", "Dinah Lance", "Oliver Queen" };
 String Name = search(emplNames, emplID);
 

 
 }
   
   
   
  
 }
   public static String search(String[] emplNames, int[]emplID) {
   
   
   Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Please enter Employee Name or ID");
   return null;
   
  } //I called it from main

Comment: public static String search(String[] emplNames, int[]emplID) {
   
   
   Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Please enter Employee Name or ID");
   return null;
   
  }//SEARCH DATABASE

Comment: it has no errors if you want you can run it, just update the prime

Answer (score 1):

Update your loop with

```
for (int i = 0; i < emplID.length; i++) {
        if ((emplID[i] > 10000) && (emplID[i] < 99999)) {
            System.out.print(emplID[i] + " - Valid ID length\n");

        } else {
            System.out.println(emplID[i] + " - Invalid ID! ID must be Five digits!\n");
            emplID[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        boolean isPrime = true;
        for (int j = 2; j < emplID[i]; j++) {
            if (emplID[i] % j == 0) {
                System.out.println(emplID[i] + " - not prime");
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            } 
        }
        if(isPrime) System.out.println(emplID[i] + " - valid prime");
    }
```

Comment: You could actually shorten the range of the loop, since no integer will be divisible by a number greater than its half: `j < emplID[i]/2`

Comment: yes you are right, there can be more updates but i was just helping with if..else loop and flag.